# Hide and Show functionality for dynamic id's at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I have buttons which are creating dynamically after form submission.

```
<template name="workflow">
  {{#each newaction}}
<div class="btn-box" >
{{> actioncardsubcontent}}

      <button type="button" class="cancelsub"  >New Action</button>
      <button type="submit" class="createbtnsub" >Show Options</button>
    </div>

{{/each}}
</template>
```

When I click on "Show Options" button the two buttons should hide and displays the content in the below template.

```
<template name="actioncardsubcontent">

    <div class="subcontent" id={{_id}} >

            <div class="modulepath"><div>{{module_list}}</div></div>
            <div class="linkto"><div>Linked To: &nbsp;<div class="linkto-color">{{link}}</div></div></div>
            <div class="description"><div>Notes:<br>{{description}}</div></div>

     <div class="btn-box showoption">
      <button type="button" class="hideoption">Hide Options</button>
      <button type="submit" class="requestextension">Request Extension</button>
    </div>      


    </div>

</template>
```

and My JS is:

```
Template.workflow.events({
 "click .createbtnsub" : function(){

      $("#"+this._id).show();
      $('.createbtnsub').hide();
      $('.cancelsub').hide();
```

With the above Js it is hiding for all the cards buttons when I click on particular card. So can anyone correct me. How to write dynamic id for those buttons to make it work for particular card.

Answer (score 0):

please try it :

```
Template.workflow.events({
 "click .createbtnsub" : function(){

      $('.createbtnsub').hide();
      $('.cancelsub').hide();


      $(this).show();
```